# Images in Bootstrap/Foundation : Text is moving on load

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm having trouble understanding a part of basic html.

When I load a page, for images unless I define the width and height, it will start at 0, and grow into the height. This causes the text to move. I'd like to not do that, but if I were to define the height, than the responsiveness of things wouldn't work. It would bend and break the images, since the width would be relative and the height not.

What would I do in this situation?

you can see what I'm talking about over at www.adarels.com

Comment: Responsiveness is not magic. Have you tried defining a `min-height` that makes your layout work for each resolution ?

Comment: I don't. You should try putting the problematic html [on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/LT4PF/), but you may be able to resolve it by correcting your layout (`.row` then x*`.span` then `.row` then y*`.span` - where `x < 12` and `y <= x`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the div using the style "display:none".

Using jquery's ready as below, you can show the divs (Note that this is not tested, would like you to try it as a suggestion):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(#divid).show();
});
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for this Rups. I ended up using a different slideshow, which allowed me to set a height, but this would have worked too.